# Best practice for loading initial data into a backbone app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I understand from the Backbone docs it is best practice to bootstrap model data into the application by embedding it in script tags that render on the initial page load.

I realize that this is done to avoid sending extra requests to the server, which will speed up page load.

But...

Does it really make that big of a difference?  I am currently calling fetch on a half-dozen models and collections on page-load, and everything seems to load very quickly.

Are there any other reasons for using this suggested method of bootstrapping data?  If not, it seems like extra effort for negligible gains, to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's fast on your development machine with just you as the user (you didn't specify the environment), but when you have many more users those requests can begin to add up. In that case, if you can bootstrap some of the data then the benefits can become more apparent. Try using chrome inspector's network monitoring pane to get more detailed information on the difference between the two methods.